# MySQL window function with parameter based frame size

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters, over-clause

I come from MS SQL Server and I'm relatively new to MySQL / MariaDB 10 (at least in a deeper way than just "SELECT * FROM [Table]"). I now searched for several hours in Google and StackOverflow, but I haven't found a soluton to my problem yet. If it's relevant in any way: I use MySQL Workbench for writing my code.

**The Background**

I have a new data logging project for saving and displaying data from several temperature and humidity sensors within the house. I save it in following table:

| ID | Time | Device | Temperature | Humidity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-09 13:34:00 | 1 | 20.1 | 52.3 |
| 2 | 2022-01-09 13:35:00 | 1 | 20.0 | 52.3 |
| 3 | 2022-01-09 13:36:00 | 1 | 20.1 | 52.4 |
| 4 | 2022-01-09 13:37:00 | 1 | 20.1 | 52.5 |
| 5 | 2022-01-09 13:38:00 | 1 | 20.0 | 52.5 |
| 6 | 2022-01-09 13:39:00 | 1 | 20.1 | 52.6 |

I query the needed data for a chart using a stored procedure. Especially the on 0.1°C rounded temperature values have the disadvantage that they naturally often change between a value of 0.1 when the temperature is pretty stable. So I thought of a moving average to smooth the values over the last 10 minutes which works perfectly with an average window function.

Here a simplified version of my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `stpGetSensorData`(sensorId INT, startDate VARCHAR(8))
BEGIN
    DECLARE FromDate DATE;
    SET FromDate = STR_TO_DATE(startDate, '%Y%m%d');

    SELECT 
        L.ID,
        L.Time,
        L.Device,
        AVG(L.Temperature) OVER (ORDER BY L.Time ROWS BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING) AS Temperature,
        AVG(L.Humidity) OVER (ORDER BY L.Time ROWS BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING) AS Humidity
    FROM
        LoggedData AS L
    WHERE
        Device = sensorId
        AND Time < DATE_ADD(FromDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        AND Time >= FromDate
    ORDER BY Time DESC;
END
```

**The challenge**

Now I thought I let the end user decide about the size of the window, i.e. an average over the last 5, 10, 30, 60, ... minutes. But when I try to insert a parameter in the window function, it leads to the error: "*averageRows is not valid at this position*".

Here the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `stpGetSensorData`(sensorId INT, startDate VARCHAR(8), averageRows INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE FromDate DATE;
    SET FromDate = STR_TO_DATE(startDate, '%Y%m%d');

    SELECT 
        L.ID,
        L.Time,
        L.Device,
        AVG(L.Temperature) OVER (ORDER BY L.Time ROWS BETWEEN averageRows PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING) AS Temperature,
        AVG(L.Humidity) OVER (ORDER BY L.Time ROWS BETWEEN averageRows PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING) AS Humidity
    FROM
        LoggedData AS L
    WHERE
        Device = sensorId
        AND Time < DATE_ADD(FromDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        AND Time >= FromDate
    ORDER BY Time DESC;
END
```

I guess it's possible to solve this using Dynamic SQL, but I try to avoid Dynamic SQL whereever possible and thought there must be a 'normal' solution as well and I'm just too blind to see it.

Any smart ideas?

Comment: you can't use variables at that position, so don't avoid dynamic sql

Comment: Create separate queries in your stored procedure and call needed query in `CASE averageRows WHEN 10 THEN {query with the frame of 10 minutes} WHEN 30 ...` statement. Alternatively - use subquery/CTE instead of window function.

Comment: *So I thought of a moving average to smooth the values over the last 10 minutes which works perfectly with an average window function.* This is incorrect. Your frame is 10 ROWS, not 10 minutes. Use RANGE frame definition. PS. `AND 0 FOLLOWING` == `AND CURRENT ROW`. And the last variant seems to be more clear.

Comment: @Akina: The way of using CASE is not a bad idea, at least as long as there are fixed windows. As soon as the user has the possibility to enter a size, it's not possible anymore.

And you're completly right for sure that it's 10 ROWS. That was a little inaccurate of me. But that's not the point of the difficulty here. The part "AND 0 FOLLOWING" was just a leftover from testing with different averages of not just past values. :)

I guess I will give both versions a try: the CASE and the Dynamic SQL one, like nbk says it would be the only way, to be completly flexible. Thank you both so far!